# Why is EO.PDF Timing Out When Converting HTML File to PDF in C#

Tags: c#, html, pdf, c#-4.0

I have the following bits of code:

```
 public static void WriteHTML(string cFile, List<Movie> mList)
        {
            int lineID = 0;
            string strMovie, strGenre, tmpGenre = null;

            // initiates streamwriter for catalog output file
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(cFile, FileMode.Create);
            StreamWriter catalog = new StreamWriter(fs);

            string strHeader = "<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n" + "<!--\r\n" + "tr#odd {\r\n" + "    background-color:#e2e2e2;\r\n" + "  vertical-align:top;\r\n" + "}\r\n" + "\r\n" + "tr#even {\r\n" + "   vertical-align:top;\r\n" + "}\r\n" + "div#title {\r\n" + "  font-size:16px;\r\n" + "    font-weight:bold;\r\n" + "}\r\n" + "\r\n" + "div#mpaa {\r\n" + "    font-size:10px;\r\n" + "}\r\n" + "\r\n" + "div#genre {\r\n" + " font-size:12px;\r\n" + "    font-style:italic;\r\n" + "}\r\n" + "\r\n" + "div#plot {\r\n" + "   height: 63px;\r\n" + "  font-size:12px;\r\n" + "    overflow:hidden;\r\n" + "}\r\n" + "-->\r\n" + "</style>\r\n" + "\r\n" + "<html>\r\n" + "    <body>\r\n" + "     <table>\r\n";
            catalog.WriteLine(strHeader);

            foreach (Movie m in mList)
            {
                strMovie = lineID == 0 ? "          <tr id=\"odd\" style=\"page-break-inside:avoid\">" : "          <tr id=\"even\" style=\"page-break-inside:avoid\">";
                catalog.WriteLine(strMovie);

                foreach (string genre in m.Genres)
                    tmpGenre += ", " + genre;

                try
                { strGenre = tmpGenre.Substring(2); }
                catch (Exception)
                { strGenre = null; }

                strMovie = "                <td>\r\n" + "                   <img src=\".\\images\\" + m.ImageFile + "\" width=\"75\" height=\"110\">\r\n" + "               </td>\r\n" + "              <td>\r\n" + "                   <div id=\"title\">" + m.Title + "</div>\r\n" + "                    <div id=\"mpaa\">" + m.Certification + " " + m.MPAA + "</div>\r\n" + "                  <div id=\"genre\">" + strGenre + "</div>\r\n" + "                   <div id=\"plot\">" + m.Plot + "</div>\r\n" + "              </td>\r\n" + "          </tr>\r\n";
                catalog.WriteLine(strMovie);
                lineID = lineID == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            }

            catalog.WriteLine("     </table>\r\n" + "   </body>\r\n" + "</html>");
            catalog.Close();
        }




        public static void WritePDF(string cFile, string pdfFile)
        {
            // Sets up PDF to write to
            EO.Pdf.HtmlToPdf.Options.PageSize = new SizeF(8.5f, 11f);
            EO.Pdf.HtmlToPdf.Options.OutputArea = new RectangleF(0.5f, .25f, 7.5f, 10.25f);

            HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl(cFile, pdfFile);
        }
```

My HTML file writes fine, but when it tried to convert the HTML file to PDF I get an exception that it times out.

I did a test previously, and had it convert the code (not the file) within the WriteHTML function and it worked great.  I have confirmed that the cFile exists and is a valid file (created previously in WriteHTML).  The path to pdfFile is valid, and the documentation does not state the file needs to already exist (.ConvertHTML did not need an existing file).

Only thing I can think of is that the catalog.html file isn't released and ready to read yet.  I made sure I closed it in the WriteHTML function.  How can I test that the file is ready to be read?

Tried setting .MaxLoadWaitTime = 120000 with no luck.

Any clues would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a battery of further testing, and scouring the EO support forums, it appears to be a limitation of the free version of EO.  It seems to have difficulty with HTML files over 3MB.

It's a shame since the EO product is very good, but not unfortunately not worth $250 IMO.